# Do you take his word against/over mine?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition seems to fit in this sentence? What will the difference in the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: `against` implies a competition. As in: "It's your word against mine." It's not clear whose word will win at this time. So they're at equal footing. Hence, `against`.

"Do you take his word over mine?" In this case, the 'taker' has already decided whose word will win. Therefore, `against` doesn't make sense here. `Over` is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally heard "your word against mine" far more frequently than I've heard "your word over mine" - I find I have an unexpected bias in that the "over" construction seems to me to indicate lesser educational attainment in the speaker.

Google ngram shows a huge distribution differential which supports my internal expectations to a large degree:

[image]

[Google NGRAM chart for these terms- English corpus, 1800-2018](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your%20word%20against%20mine%2C%20your%20word%20over%20mine&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20word%20against%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20word%20over%20mine%3B%2Cc0)

Of course, knowing the most commonly-used between the two variants doesn't answer the portion of your question pertaining to implications - for that I would say I agree with @Tushar Raj's take on the implication of the phrasing, with a caveat - the active person doing the assuming is **not** in fact the "taker" - the use of "over" in this phrase implies that the ***asker*** is *assuming* that *the person to whom they've addressed the question* has at some level *already decided* that "his" word has been deemed more credible than "mine"...

Hope this helps.